# What is the difference between well-defined and well-formed?

Tags: logic

Well-defined and well-formed seem like pretty much the same concepts. I did read through the Wikipedia pages on both subjects. 
Can you elaborate on how they are different and provide examples (on a beginner level)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well-defined is a property of *functions*; well-formed is a property of *logical propositions*. A well-defined function is any function that is single-valued (see [Tim Gowers's site](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/welldefined.html) for a good explanation) and a well-formed proposition is any proposition that makes sense syntactically. This function is not well defined:
$$
f(a/b)=a+b.
$$
This proposition is not well-formed:
$$
PQ\land.
$$
(EDIT: It actually is well-formed if you use [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). But the string $(P\implies(QQ))$ is definitely not well-formed)
Does that clear up the matter?

Comment: sigh... PQ∧ is actually well-formed!  It's just in reverse Polish notation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation  That said PQ∧R is not well-formed given that ∧ is a binary operation.

Comment: Okay, fair enough: I forgot about reverse Polish notation. Let me make something worse.

Comment: I would add that “single-valued” is not always easy to determine. Consider a function $f:[0,1)\to\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ with the following definition: $f(x)$=$d_2$ if $x=0.d_1d_2d_3\dots$. (Here, $0.d_1d_2d_3$ is the decimal fraction with digits $d_1, d_2, \dots$.) This seems single-valued, because it seems to tell you exactly what $f(x)$ is. But real numbers don’t all have unique decimal fraction representations: $\frac{1}{10}=0.1000 \dots =0.099999\dots$, so does $f(\frac{1}{10})$ equal 0 or 9? In this case, $f$ isn’t a well-defined function.

Comment: I like that example!

Comment: As shown by the "counterexample" by Doug, *well-formed* is realtive to a set of *formation rules* : thus, you must specify an *alphabet* (set of synbols admissible), and then *formation rules*, defining the set of *expressions* (and not propositions) admissible.

Comment: Well defined is also a property of sets: a set is well defined if it is possible to tell whether a given object is, or is not, an element of that set.